# Schroedinger equation and an infinite universe

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, schroedinger-equation, universe

Given that the Schroedinger equation states that a particle can be found an infinite distance away from its "center" and the universe is infinite, why don't we find infinite particles at any given point?

Comment: I think I understand why you have jumped to the conclusion that we should be able to find many particles at a point in space. However, your reasoning was not evident to me at first. I suggest explaining your line of reasoning more thoroughly in your post to prevent further down votes.

Answer (score 0):

> Given that the Schrodinger equation states that a particle can be found an infinite distance away from its "center"

The Schrodinger equation does not say this. The Schrodinger equation just tells us how quantum states evolve over time give the Hamiltonian that describes the system.$^*$

You are just thinking about an axiom of QM that says that you can express your quantum state $|\psi\rangle$ as a superposition of eigenstates of a given observable. The amplitude of each term in this superposition can then tell you the probability of measuring that corresponding eigenvalue. For position measurements, the probability amplitude for measuring a particle to be at position $x$ is $|\psi(x)|^2$, where $\psi(x)$ is typically called the "wave function" defined by $$|\psi\rangle=\int\psi(x)\,|x\rangle\,\text dx$$ where $|x\rangle$ is an eigenstate of the position operator.

Since, for certain systems, $\psi(x)$ is non-zero at all points in space, technically then there is a non-zero probability of finding the particle at all locations in space. However, something to keep in mind is that $\psi(x)$ typically drops off fairly quickly away from the expected location to find the particle. Then, since the probability amplitude is given by $|\psi(x)|^2$, the probability will drop even more quickly as we move away from the particle's "center" (this isn't a common term, so I hope I am understanding you correctly).

> why don't we find infinite particles at any given point?

I suppose you mean why don't we find all particles in the universe at any given point (there are many particles in the universe, but not an infinite amount). Since our probabilities drop off fairly quickly away from the expected position of the particle, we don't have to worry about this. Also, keep in mind that "non-zero probability" does not mean "100% going to happen". In addition, not all particles exhibit "quantum behavior" macroscopically. Decoherence with the environment needs to be considered as well. I don't think you need to worry about your own molecules suddenly appearing on the moon ;)

---

$^*$Also keep in mind that the Schrodinger equation does not describe all systems and particles. This is why QFT, QED, the standard model, etc. was developed.

Answer (score 0):

> Given that the Schroedinger equation states that a particle can be found an infinite distance away from its "center" and the universe is infinite, why don't we find infinite particles at any given point?

Assuming your statement is correct, the fact that we do not find infinite particles would tell us that

1) the universe is finite

2) the mass/energy of the universe is finite

But the Schrodinger equations is no longer used to describe particle physics, it was useful for non relativistic bound states in  a potential ( the hydrogen atom).

The mainstream theory of particle physics is the [standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model), a quantum field theoretical one.

In this model the plane wave solutions of  the relativistic quantum mechanical wave equations(Dirac, Klein Gordon, quantized Maxwell) are used to define quantum fields up to infinity, for each particle in the table in the link. Creation and annihilation operators work on these fields to allow calculating with the help of Feynman diagrams interactions and decays. Free particles are modeled with [wave packets](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/wpack.html) which localize them in space and time.